# ImproperlyConfigured: You need to specify NAME in your Django settings file

Tags: python, django

I'm almost there!! in deploying EveryBlock's ebcode in my mac OSX - here is my settings.py:

http://pastebin.com/ndQ57LCH

This is the entire error:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 280, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 674, in __call__
    return self.application(environ, start_response)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 234, in __call__
    signals.request_started.send(sender=self.__class__)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 172, in send
    response = receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 90, in reset_queries
    for conn in connections.all():
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 101, in all
    return [self[alias] for alias in self]
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 93, in __getitem__
    conn = backend.DatabaseWrapper(db, alias)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/backends/postgis/base.py", line 11, in __init__
    self.ops = PostGISOperations(self)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/backends/postgis/operations.py", line 91, in __init__
    vtup = self.postgis_version_tuple()
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/backends/postgis/operations.py", line 445, in postgis_version_tuple
    version = self.postgis_lib_version()
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/backends/postgis/operations.py", line 425, in postgis_lib_version
    return self._get_postgis_func('postgis_lib_version')
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/backends/postgis/operations.py", line 406, in _get_postgis_func
    cursor = self.connection._cursor()
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py", line 121, in _cursor
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("You need to specify NAME in your Django settings file.")
ImproperlyConfigured: You need to specify NAME in your Django settings file.
```

Please advise.

Comment: Sharing the whole config (including secret key etc) might not be the best plan...

Comment: its ok this is for testing not production so I don't really care - though thanks for your concern.

Answer (score 5):

1. Use *either* the one-database setup (`DATABASE_xxx = ...`) *or* the multiple-database (`DATABASES` dict) setup
2. **Don't prepend "DATABASE_" to the dictionary keys**, e.g. in `DATABASES["users"]`). This is where the error comes from.
3. Don't share your database password on SO

Answer (score 1):

I think you might have forgotten to set the `NAME` property in your `DATABASES` setting:

[DATABASES setting](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/?from=olddocs#databases)